# SQL inserting data based on nested xpath

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2012

I have a simple insert statement that I am working on. This query inserts a core record, returns an ID, and then inserts a one or more tasks into another table. For each of those tasks, I need to do an additional insert into a 3rd table.

I am having a little trouble trying to figure out how to set this up due to the second insert statement happening before the 3rd, so I am not sure about how to get the `identity` from each insert to pass to query 3.

```
DECLARE @requestID INT;

    -- Insert the core request details
    INSERT INTO esas.Request (Requestor, Justification, CreatedBy, DateCreated)
    SELECT @requestor,
           @justification,
           @creator,
           GETUTCDATE()

    -- Define the core request ID
    SET @requestID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Add tasks
    INSERT INTO esas.Task
            ( RequestID ,
              ToolID ,
              QID ,
              Action
            )
     SELECT  @requestID,
             ParamValues.x1.value('tool[1]', 'INT'),
             ParamValues.x1.value('user[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
             ParamValues.x1.value('action[1]', 'INT)')
     FROM @tasks.nodes('/request/task') AS ParamValues(x1);

     -- For each task, add any associated roles (stuck here)
     INSERT INTO esas.TaskRoles
                ( TaskID, 
                  RoleID, 
                  ActionID )
     VALUES  ( 0, -- TaskID - int
               0, -- RoleID - int
               0  -- ActionID - int
               )
```

In the last insert, I need to pass the `PK/AI` the `TaskID` created from "Add Tasks" to another table, along with the `roleID` and `action` from the XML string.

Here is my XML structure:

```
<request>
    <task>
        <tool>123</tool>
        <user>4567</user>
        <roles>
            <role>
                <roleID>12</roleID>
                <action>1</action>
            </role>
            <role>
                <roleID>1245</roleID>
                <action>0</action>
            </role>
            <role>
                <roleID>678</roleID>
                <action>1</action>
            </role>
        </roles>
    </task>
</request>
```

My confusion is due to knowing that `INSERT INTO esas.Task` is going to all happen at once before moving on so I am not sure how to pass each identity to the next insert along with its corresponding details in the XML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out using xpath and joining the `tasks` table after the data had been inserted.

```
     -- For each task, add any associated roles
     INSERT INTO esas.TaskRoles
                ( TaskID, 
                  RoleID, 
                  ActionID )
     SELECT  t.TaskID,
             ParamValues.x1.value('roleID[1]', 'INT'),
             ParamValues.x1.value('action[1]', 'INT')
     FROM esas.Task AS t
     JOIN @tasks.nodes('/request/task/roles/role') AS ParamValues(x1)
     ON t.RequestID = @requestID
     AND t.ToolID =  ParamValues.x1.value('../../tool[1]', 'INT')
     AND t.QID =  ParamValues.x1.value('../../user[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
```